# Join on Range in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database table like this:

```
ID | Meal            |Person
--------------------------------
1  | Early Beakfast  | Abc
2  | Breakfast       | Abc
3  | Lunch           | Abc
4  | Afternoon Snack | Abc
5  | Evening Snack   | Abc
7  | Dinner          | Abc
8  | late Night Snack| Abc
9  | Afternoon Snack | Def
10 | Evening Snack   | Def
```

I want an output like this:

```
Anchor          | Before          | After            | Person
----------------------------------------------------------------
Afternoon Snack | Early Breakfast | Evening Snack    | Abc
Afternoon Snack | Breakfast       | Dinner           | Abc
Afternoon Snack | Lunch           | Late Night Snack | Abc
Afternoon Snack | NULL            | Evening Snack    | Def
```

What is the best approach to get this result?

I have tried using self join on ID IN (ID+1, ID+2,...ID+N) but it's not feasible.
NOTE: This is just a sample data. The actual data contains 2M+ records. However, the anchor remains the same.

Comment: What if the table has an even number of records, how do you define the anchor and how do you spread the records?

Comment: The anchor remains "Afternoon Snack" throughout. I want to get records which come before afternoon snack & after it. I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Something like this  `with t(x) as (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) select unnest(array(select x from t where x < 3)), unnest(array(select x from t where x > 3));` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create groups based on the count of afternoon snacks (a cumulative sum) and then aggregate:

```
select 'Afternoon Snack',
       max(case when seqnum = 0 then meal end) as before,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then meal end) as after
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, grp, (meal <> 'Afternoon Snack') order by id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) filter (where meal = 'Afternoon Snack') over (partition by person order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp in (0, 1)
group by person, seqnum
order by person, seqnum;
```